# "Import Error lxml" is shown in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, lxml, pygal

I am trying to run using pygal libray to show graph in AWS lambda.But this error is shown, even I have already installed lxml.[deployment_package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcmWp.png)
[my_source_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Hzb.png)
[import_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtw9d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because lxml contains binary pre-compiled libraries that it uses. When you install lxml locally on your Windows machine, you install a Windows-compatible version of it. However this is not compatible with the Lambda execution environment which is Linux based.

So you have to create a Lambda compatible deployment package. You have couple of options doing so. You can use `sam build --use-container`, you can build the libraries in a Docker environment and then zip those, etc. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469437/1370986) as well.