# Unable to import libraries in AWS Lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to import pymysql lib in my lambda function. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695187/import-libraries-in-lambda-layers), I used the following folder structure as shown in the image below but I get an error.

[image]

When I have the lib folders in the same level as my function(as shown below), I am able to execute the lambda function without any error. I might end up using few libraries, so I want the dependencies to be isolated in a folder 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked uses a Lambda layer, however you deployed your function using a deployment package together with its dependencies. The paths of the libraries are not configured correctly. If you want to deploy this way, follow [Lambda Deployment Package in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) guide. You basically need to package the libraries as you showed in the second image.

You can alternatively create a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path), which is a ZIP archive that contains libraries, a custom runtime, or other dependencies. You do not need to include your libraries in your deployment package if you use Layers.